# Is potential energy always inversely proportional to separation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, conservation-laws, potential-energy, collision

This is a question from Class 11 Physics NCERT. [image]

The answer is that only graph (v) is correct and the reason given here is that potential energy varies inversely with separation. But does that always have to be the case?

Also, I had learnt that during elastic collision, all the kinetic energy momentarily converts to elastic potential energy due to deformation, which means that potential energy should be maximum. But here the graph shows that the potential energy is minimum during collision.

I'm certain I am missing a key concept here. Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Notice the label on the horizontal axis? What happens to the separation between the balls' centers during a collision (unless there is more text that you haven't shown us I suppose that you are expected to intuit that $R$ is the radius of an individual ball)?

Comment: There isn't any more text but I assumed that R was the radius of the balls too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But here the graph shows that the potential energy is minimum during collision.

But it doesn't. Keep in mind that $r$ becomes *smaller* as the balls get closer together and then becomes *larger* as they move apart. The horizontal axis is not time. So the potential energy actually increases to a maximum at the minimum separation, and then it goes back down as the balls separate.

As for the other points, it makes sense that you want $V$ to increase as $r$ decreases. This is because
$$F=-\frac{\text dV}{\text dr}$$
The inverse relationship between $V$ and $r$ means that the force is pushing the balls in contact towards being farther apart.

None of the other answer choices give you the correct force behavior (check for yourself).

To answer your title question, this does not always have to be the case. But for your system we don't want any attraction between the balls, so we do want this behavior here. It doesn't necessarily have to be inversely proportional, but it does need to monotonically decrease as $r$ increases (i.e. an inverse relationship).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Did you mean force= -dV/dr? Also here: "The inverse relationship between V and r means that the force is pushing the balls in contact towards being farther apart." Is this because we want the system to have minimum potential energy?

Comment: @laksheya We want $dV/dr$ to be decreasing with increasing $r$ (force pushing to larger $r$) and we want this decreasing behavior to become weaker at larger distances (stronger force for smaller separation). I'm unsure what you mean by having the potential energy at a minimum, since the potential energy changes during the collision.

Comment: By your argument, wouldn't the van der Waals and Lennard-Jones potentials be disallowed?

Comment: @garyp Can you expand more on that? I'm not sure I follow. Do colliding billiard balls follow those potentials?

Comment: @AaronStevens Oh sorry I misunderstood you earlier. Thank you!

Comment: I glossed over the words "billiard balls" in the OP.   But having noticed that, I might argue that none of the choices applies to an elastic collision between two billiard balls. $i$ or $vi$ might if the KE and energy scales were just right. So could (arguably) $iii$.  I can't see how $ii$ or $iv$ could be a correct description.   The soft nature of $v$ is at variance with the hard nature of billiard balls.  To me it seems that the question is poorly constructed, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @garyp $iii$ doesn't work because it suggests there is an (unstable) equilibrium past when the balls come into contact, past which the balls will actually become attracted to each other. $i$ and $vi$ are essentially equivalent, but they both suggest an infinite force only at the exact point of contact. I guess the question doesn't want to assume rigid billiard balls. I think saying the only choice is $v$ makes sense to me. Since there are no numbers here, to can argue the scale of $v$ does follow the "hard" nature of billiard balls.

Comment: Yeah.   I still think the problem is lousy.  $v$ allows billiard balls to pass through each other.   That *might* help my eight-ball game.  I'm re-reading again.  The OP says that $v$ is "correct".  Does that mean that $v$ is the correct answer, i.e. is the only impossible selection?  Or correct in the sense that it is the only selection that is physically possible?   Signing off ... too much time on this already.  :-)

Comment: @garyp $v$ is the only graph that is physically possible. They are not passing through each other. They are assumed to not be rigid, and $r$ is the distance between their centers. Therefore, when they collide their centers can become closer than $2R$. If they were rigid then $i$ or $vi$ would make more sense, although it wouldn't make sense to have a potential defined for $r<2R$ then.

Comment: I said I'd shut up, but ... what billiard ball behaves like that?  Allows the distance between centers to be zero? And *does* allow them to pass through each other if the KE is greater than $V(0)$?  And I'm still not sure what the OP means by "correct".  I hope I can keep my promise to be quiet now.

Comment: @garyp True, I suppose really it should be $V\to\infty$ as $r\to0$ Oh well. I'm not sure why you think you need to be quiet though? I think it's good points to raise.

Comment: @garyp Hey, by correct I meant that was the correct answer. I don't really know much about chemistry to deem something physically possible or not, yet. :)

Comment: @laksheya Thanks for the clarification.  The truth from my point of view is that *all* of the choices are impossible, and that it's arguable that *v* is closest to being possible.   The problem is defective.

Comment: @garyp I think you're right as well. All of the other questions in my book seem to view the collision between billiard balls as elastic and undergoing this extreme deformation, so I didn't really question it. Thank you for your insight!